# How to connect to Oracle database on VM1 from host with 11gClient

Tags: oracle, linux, connectivity, vmware

I have a VM running Oracle Linux 6.5, I loaded Oracle server x64bit and created a database. The database functions fine and the listener is up and running for the database. I want to connect to the server (VM1) using SQL Developer from host. But I have no idea how to do this.

Can anyone point me to DETAILED instructions on the easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: You would get a detailed answer if you start with a detailed question. What virtualization, what IP address has the host, which the guest. What networking mode is used, what bind address does the listener use, can you ping and ssh into the guest, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the VM software you are using. In case of VirtualBox you have to check what type of connection you set (NAT, bridge, etc); if using NAT you need to enable a port-forward to the listener port: e.g. TCP 21521 on host, TCP 1521 on VM).

Also check if iptables firewall is enabled on your VM.

Comment: Hi, I'm using vmware and the connection is Host-Only.

Comment: I add another adapter network and set with NAT and enable port-forward like you said but this doesn't work. BTW, I try the command tnsping but give me this error : http://postimg.org/image/xijvfc0a3/

Comment: what IP did you get in the guest? Is it pingable from the host? I think you do not need another NAT adapter, you just need to edit the host-only one

Answer (score 0):

The New Connection tool in SQL Developer has the following fields as input for the basic connection type. I will describe what to input in each field.

Connection Name: The name you want the connection to appear as in the SQL Developer connection manager.

Username: The database user you wish to connect as. Considering your circumstances, sys or system would be ideal (these users are created by default)

Password: The database user password associated with Username. From the SQL*PLUS client you can reset this password using "ALTER USER  identified by ;"

Hostname: The name of the server which the database instance resides on. In your case, this would be VM1.

Port: In 99% of cases, this is 1521 (Default Oracle port).

SID/Service Name: Tick one of the radio buttons. For SID, it is the name of the database instance. If you run the following on your server, you can find this:

```
    ps -ef | grep pmon | grep -v grep
```

You'll see a result that looks like

```
    ora_pmon_<SID>
```

Alternatively, for Service Name, if you login to SQL*PLUS and issue "show parameter service_name" you can see the service name of the database and plug that in.

There are many other options visible, but that will give you a database connection so you can start running sql statements in SQL Developer without issues.